# uninstal ubuntu from bootable ubuntu pc

Tags: system-installation

I have a laptop with preinstalled Ubuntu. But I want to remove the Ubuntu and install a server in my laptop. Someone says the steps to format and install the windows server or XP.

Comment: @Web-E the link contains posts to uninstall ubuntu or windows from a dual-boot system.But the OP ask to completely remove ubuntu and install windows on that partition.

Comment: Close voters, OP wants to nuke his **single-boot** Ubuntu and install Windows. **He doesn't have Dual Boot.**

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP will nuke Ubuntu when you try to install it. Just **make sure you have backups** in an external disk of all your important files, then start the installation. The steps after that you should ask in [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0):

- Boot [**Gprted**](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) live disk.Right click on the partition where you installed Ubuntu,and then format it to `ntfs` file system.Apply the changes and shutdown the pc.
- Boot windows xp live disk and install xp on the formatted partition.

Answer (score 0):

Simply install your OS of choice over Ubuntu, however, if you are not installing another os, here is how to nuke Ubuntu: (given that it is installed on /dev/sda)

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda
```